# MySQL: syntax error when trying to delete from table

Tags: mysql, syntax, delete-row

So I'm trying to run the following code to delete a record from a table when thhe customer ID is 100

```
DELETE FROM workoutplan
JOIN account ON workoutplan.Account_Username = account.Username
JOIN customer ON account.Customer_idCustomer = customer.idCustomer
WHERE Customer_idCustomer = 100
```

However I get the following error

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN account ON workoutplan.Account_Username = account.Username
JOIN customer O' at line 2
```

Comment: The error shows `* FROM workoutplan ...` but your example shows only `DELETE FROM workoutplan`.  Do you by chance have `DELETE * FROM workoutplan` in your actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE workoutplan 
FROM   workoutplan w 
       JOIN account 
         ON w.account_username = account.username 
       JOIN customer 
         ON account.customer_idcustomer = customer.idcustomer
WHERE  customer_idcustomer = 100
```